# IIS URL Rewrite/Redirect to different website on same server

Tags: url, iis, url-rewrite-module

am trying to figure out if IIS 7 can do this:

www.somesite.com => maps to port 80 (already works)
www.somesite.com/Integration -> localhost:2002/Integration.

I am still experimenting with the IIS Rewrite, but haven't got this working yet. Haven't seen an answer in StackOverflow results.

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="Integration" />
    </rewriteMaps>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Integration" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="https://www.somesite.com/integration/*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{Integration:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(/integration+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:2002/integration/xyz.svc" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```